# Modbus TCP read register

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient, modbus

I am working with modbus via TCP and able to write to a register but not read it.  When ever I read the address the return value is 0. Below is the code where I read from the address (tried two different ways).  The desire is to adjust the register based on the current value. **What do I need to do different to read the register?**

If I set the register to 1024 and then run the code below it shows the register is 0.  The register is used to turn on/off lights so I know I am able to write to the register as I can see the light is turned on.

```
Using sMBClient As TcpClient = New TcpClient(TextBoxIP.Text, 502)
            StatusMsg(String.Format("connecting to ip {0} and port {1}", TextBoxIP.Text, 502))
            sMBClient.ReceiveTimeout = 2000
            sMBClient.SendTimeout = 2000
            Dim sMBMaster As ModbusTcpMaster = ModbusTcpMaster.CreateTcp(sMBClient)

            registerValues = sMBMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(TextBoxModbusAddress.Text, 1)
            registerValueCurrent = registerValues(0)
            StatusMsg(String.Format("holding register address value is {0}", registerValueCurrent))

            registerValues = sMBMaster.ReadInputRegisters(TextBoxModbusAddress.Text, 1)
            registerValueCurrent = registerValues(0)
            StatusMsg(String.Format("input register address value is {0}", registerValueCurrent))

            If IsBitSet(registerValueCurrent, Carousels(3).ModbusBitValue) Then
                registerValueNew = ClearBit(registerValueCurrent, Carousels(cIdx).ModbusBitValue)
            Else
                registerValueNew = SetBit(registerValueCurrent, Carousels(cIdx).ModbusBitValue)
            End If

            StatusMsg(String.Format("Sending value {1} for Zone 1 register ({0})", TextBoxModbusAddress.Text, registerValueNew))
            sMBMaster.WriteSingleRegister(TextBoxModbusAddress.Text, registerValueNew)

        End Using
```

**Update**
so if the holding register is the one I want (according to Alessandro) then why is returning 0.  What am I missing?

```
sMBMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(Convert.ToUInt16(TextBoxModbusAddress.Text), 1)
```

Comment: May be read the register?  You have a master/slave communication system.  The client is the master and the Mod Bus the slave.  The slave only responds to commands.  Some commands will return response and others may not.  To read a register you first have to give a command telling which register to read.  On some devices they may be a Read/Write register and before reading you must set the mode to read.  You need to read the user manual.

Comment: Holding registers and input registers are different registers altogether. Holding register 1 does not replicate on input register 1, unless the embedded sw is instructed to copy any change of value of holding register to input register. Also you are passing TextBox strings in place of Integer in all methods. That's a type mismatch.

Comment: when using WriteSingleRegister where does it go (holding register, input register, something else)?  Since  I can get the WriteSingleRegister to work I just want to read it back.

Comment: It goes in the holding register and you can read it back the same holding register. A holding register is R/W. An input register is Read only.